# Relationship is working in Laravel Tinker but not within controller

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I made a manyToMany relationship and want to return that in my php code which is not working, but when I run the same code in tinker it is working for some reason. What am I missing?

// Firma

```
public function auftraege()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany("Auftrag", 'auftraege_firma');
}
```

// Auftrag

```
public function firmen()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany("Firma", 'auftraege_firma');
}
```

// works in tinker

```
$firma = App\Firma::first();
$firma->auftraege
```

// Does not work in php Controller

```
$firma = App\Firma::first();
return $firma->auftraege
```

Getting 500 Error

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your controller code, I can only notice two things. Change your controller code like this:

```
$firma = \App\Firma::first();
return $firma->auftraege;
```

You are missing `\` before the `App` namespace and also the semicolon is missing in the return statement.

Please also change the relationshps like this:

```
public function auftraege()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Auftrag::class, 'auftraege_firma');
}

public function firmen()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Firma::class, 'auftraege_firma');
}
```

The reason it was working from tinker is that by default tinker sets the namespace to `App` for the current tinker session. That's why even though you didn't specify the `App` namespace, tinker was able to parse the proper namespace.

Comment: Glad to help. If that solves your problem then accept the answer. This helps stackoverflow mark the question as "Solved".

Comment: You are a savior. Thank you :)